# Caching in Active Model Serializers increases response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to cache a serializer but there is a problem with caching is that it slows down the response time.

the serializer looks like

```
class FeedSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  cached
  embed :ids
  has_one :owner, include: true, serializer: UserSerializer, root: :users
  has_one :post,  include: true
  attributes  :id, :type

  def cache_key
    Digest::SHA1.hexadigest([object.cache_key, owner, post].join('/'))
  end
end
```

and i added a `cache_key` to the class like this

```
class Feed
  # ...some fields and class functions...
  field :key, type: String
  field :title, type: String

  def cache_key
    [ self.key, self.title ]
   end
end
```

and in the controller

```
 # GET /feeds
  def index
    @feed = current_user.feeds.recent.includes(:owners)
    render json: @feed
  end
```

the problem is that this implementation slows the controller although the cache hits...

```
14:03:40 web.1       | Cache read: feed_serializer/f81fef05948d17506bf0d0923aa35e593208a21c/serializable-hash
14:03:40 web.1       | Cache fetch_hit: feed_serializer/f81fef05948d17506bf0d0923aa35e593208a21c/serializable-hash
14:03:40 web.1       | Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 46.9ms)
```

and without the caching implementation the same request returned in **29ms** ?

```
14:05:38 web.1       | Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 26.9ms)
```

Any ideas what would be wrong?

The `object.cache_key` returns a consistent cache key that is invalidated when some of the invalidating attributes are changed...

The serializer also returns a consistent cache key... and that cached version is found. and if i delegated the cache_key to the object ... the sideloaded relations (owner,post) are not loaded... the response doesn't contain them?